# Removing rows where the first entries are duplicate (R data frames)

Tags: r

I know that duplicate rows in a data frame X can be removed using X = unique(X). However, I have a situation where the entire row is not necessarily duplicate, rather, I have rows with the same first element (a barcode identifier) and the numeric values differ slightly. I want to remove all but the first instance of duplicates. For instance, for

```
A  1.01 2.03 3.03
A  1.02 2.02 3.01
B  3.9  4.2  6.6
C  0.1  0.21 0.99
C  0.11 0.22 0.99
C  0.12 0.21 0.98
```

I want to return

```
A  1.01 2.03 3.03
B  3.9  4.2  6.6
C  0.1  0.21 0.99
```

I can get the listing A,B,C using unique(X[,1]), but then

```
which(X[,1] %in% unique(X[,1]))
```

gives all instances of A,B,C, so that X[which(X[,1] %in% unique(X[,1])),] won't work. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: This is textbook use case for the function `duplicated`. I'm looking for a reference question...

Comment: `X[duplicated(round(X[,1],1)),]` ?

Comment: Thanks, the only stackoverflow threads I was able to find dealt with removing entire duplicate columns or entries., !duplicated gives exactly what I need.